# Formatting a string

Tags: asp.net

I have got a string in the form:

```
8 AM;10:15 AM;3:30 PM;6:15 PM
```

which i need to format in the form

```
8 AM-10:15 AM, 3:30 PM-6:15 PM
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do string splitting on `;`, like this

```
var parts = s.Split(";".ToCharArray());
```

Then you could use the parts, like this:

```
var result = string.Format("{0}-{1}, {2}-{3}", parts);
```

This requires that the string always contains 4 parts.